# How to invalidate previous JWT token after refresh

Tags: spring, security, authentication, jwt

In our application new JWT token is returned in a cookie each time user sends a request, even though previous has still much lifetime. If user makes multiple request in a short period of time, there exists multiple valid tokens almost full lifetime on each. Browser is of course using the latest one, but someone may still use the previous ones to impersonate user.

Is there way to invalidate the previous token when dispatching a new one, or is the only choice to dispatch new token only when there is not much lifetime on the last one?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to 'invalidate' tokens is by keeping track of them statefully.

This usually means doing something like keeping a key/value cache of tokens that are valid, and invalid, and checking incoming request tokens against these lists on each request.

The downside to doing things this way is that you lose a lot of the 'stateless' benefits of JWTs (since you are still checking a centralized store for token validity), but the benefit is that you can be more 'secure' by immediately revoking tokens you no longer want service-able.

One workaround is to have your access tokens be extremely short lived (5 minutes or so), to minimize any abuse.

Comment: How about embedding the client IP into a token, and compare the upcoming request IP with the validated token's IP? This would prevent malicious user from fetching sensitive data with a stolen token (though he could still POST by spoofing his IP, if he could also obtain CSRF token)

Comment: You could try this, but IPS are not unique identifiers. Especially on public networks (cell phones, office wifi, etc). I wouldn't do that if you are building a security sensitive app.

Comment: Fair enough, NAT could also be problematic

Comment: Spring comes with a JWT-token-store that can easily be used via configuration. It allows to invalidate the refresh Tokens. So using a short enough validity time for access tokens you do not loose the statelessness completely. You would have to check with your authentication Service for refreshing access tokens anyway.